# type casting desctructured property

Tags: typescript

I have a nextjs router hook where i am destructuring the following way.

```js
const {
  query: { run_id },
} = useRouter();
```

the run_id is of following type

```js
run_id: string | string[] | undefined
```

i would like to type cast as following, but it doesnt work, what am i missing here ?????

```js
const {
  query: { run_id  as string},
} = useRouter();
```

Answer (score 1):

You (sadly) have to declare the whole type here.

```
const {
  query: { run_id },
} : { query: { run_id: string } } = useRouter();
```

Comment: indeed sad.

i think i would end up doing this way

```js  
const runId = run_id as string; 

```